# Múltiplos formulários idênticos Dwoo

Tags: dwoo, template

Tenho um formulário construído usando o `Template Engine` `Dwoo` que possui três variáveis (de dados especificos para os atributos "name" e "value"), 
este formulário será inserido multiplas vezes dentro de um outro template porém como o nome da variavel tem de ser o mesmo da chave do array de dados que é passado na invocação do template, logo como farei para que o valor destas variaveis seja modificado a cada novo formulário?

Código do template do formulário:

```
<form class="form-inline" role="form" action="#" method="get">
    <div class="form-group">
        <label for="country">Country</label>
        <select class="form-control country" name="country">
            <option value="all">All (WorldWide)</option>
        </select>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <button class="btn btn-default" type="submit" name={$search} value={$search}>Search</button>
        <button class="btn btn-default" type="submit" name={$save_pdf} value={$save_pdf}>Save in PDF</button>
        <button class="btn btn-default" type="submit" name={$save_png} value={$save_png}>Save in PNG</button>
    </div>
</form>
```

Código php que "printa" o template

```
<?php
    session_start();

    require_once '../../../vendor/autoload.php';

    $dwoo = new Dwoo\Core();
    $dwoo->setCompileDir('../../../assets/compiled/');
    $dwoo->setTemplateDir('../../../assets/templates/');

    $data = array();

    if((isset($_SESSION['email']) == true) && (isset($_SESSION['pass']) == true)){
        $data['page'] = 'site-statistics.php';
        $data['search'] = 'form_1_search';
        $data['$save_pdf'] = 'form_1_save_pdf';
        $data['$save_png'] = 'form_1_save_png';
        $dwoo->output('site-statistics.tpl', $data);
    }else{
        header('Location:index-admin.php');
    }
?>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Para resolver o problema da inserção de múltiplos valores a um mesma variável eu mudo o local de atribuição do valor da variável do arquivo responsável pela view para a atribuição anterior ao include do formulário desta forma:

Código de inclusão do template do formulário no template da página:

```
    {assign 'form_1_search' search}
    {assign 'form_1_save_pdf' save_pdf}
    {assign 'form_1_save_png' save_png}
    {include file='components/body/body-select-country2.tpl'}
```

Código PHP que "printa" a o template

```
<?php
    session_start();

    require_once '../../../vendor/autoload.php';

    $dwoo = new Dwoo\Core();
    $dwoo->setCompileDir('../../../assets/compiled/');
    $dwoo->setTemplateDir('../../../assets/templates/');

    $data = array();

    if((isset($_SESSION['email']) == true) && (isset($_SESSION['pass']) == true)){
        $data['page'] = 'site-statistics.php';
        $dwoo->output('site-statistics.tpl', $data);
    }else{
        header('Location:index-admin.php');
    }
?>
```